# jquery click question

Tags: jquery

My html:

```
<div id="menu"><ul><li>menu one<ul>
<li><a id="home">home</a></li>
<li><a id="contact">contact us</a></li>
</ul></li></ul></div>
```

Jquery :

```
    $('#menu').click(function(){
        alert($(this).find('a').attr('id'));
    });
```

I want to find value of a clicked. my code return empty.

Comment: How about bind the event to $('#menu a') and then just do alert($(this).attr('id'))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#menu a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

If you want the id, then do

```
$('#menu a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your .find('a') will return multiple elements. If you want to display each of their values loop using .each(). Else do something like this: .find('a')[0].attr('id')

Looping code:

xxx.find('a').each( alert($(this).attr('id')); )

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, it returns "home" every time as that's the first descendant `a` of the `div`. Perhaps you're looking something more like

```
  $('#menu a').click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });​
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/rsbPt/

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this won't work is because `$(this).find('a')` returns an array, thus you need to iterate over all of the anchors in `#menu` to obtain their `id`. You can do that with the `.each()` function:

```
$('#menu').click(function(){
  $(this).find('a').each(function(){ alert(this.id) });
});
```

Will give you two `alert()` for the HTML you gave, each with a different `id`. You can then replace the `alert()` with whatever function you need to perform on each of the anchors.